# Power BI: Trailing twelve month variable on computed field doesn't update with time slicer

Tags: graph, powerbi, analytics, reporting, powerbi-desktop

I am confronted with the following situation:

**Context:**

I want to create a graph that shows the evolution of my sales over the last 12 months (Trailing Twelve months - TTM) BUT where each month is already the sum of the last 12 months (Moving Annul Total - MAT). And I'd like this view to change according to a time slicer. For example, if I choose the month of May 23, I should see:

The month of May 23', the sum of the months from May 22 to May 23.
The month of April 23', the sum of april 22 to april 23.
The month of March 23', the sum of march 22 to march 23.
Etc... for a total of 12 months

**Problem:**

My problem is that the graph doesn't follow the time slicer at all. When I put a month in my slicer, the graph gives me a single value for the last 30 days, whereas I'd like to see the last 12 months.

[Image of my power bi board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPKCe.png)

**This is what I've done:**

I created a value for the MAT of sales

```
Sales_MAT = CALCULATE( sum(Sales[Sales]),DATESINPERIOD('Date Dimension'[DateDimension],MAX('Date Dimension'\[DateDimension\]),-12,MONTH) )
```

I created a value allowing me to have the last 12 months

```
TTM_Total_Sales = VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Date Dimension'\[DateDimension\])
VAR PreviousDate = DATE(YEAR(CurrentDate),MONTH(CurrentDate)-12,DAY(CurrentDate))
VAR Result =
CALCULATE(

        Sales[Sales_MAT],
    
        FILTER(
    
            ALL('Date Dimension'[DateDimension]),
    
           'Date Dimension'[DateDimension]>=PreviousDate && 'Date Dimension'[DateDimension]<=CurrentDate
    
        )

)

RETURN

Result
```

And I don't understand what else I need to do....

Already thank you for your help !

For those who prefer to work with a sample file, you can download it here (through "We transfer"):https://wetransfer.com/downloads/709319a485573e6a800731939bcd98ff20230809132758/46c7c0